# Cannot Get haskell-language-server running - duplicate symbol "sqlite3_fts3_may_be_corrupt"

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell-language-server

hoping someone can help with this

So, I would like to get the haskell-language-server running, in the context of the plutus-pioneers-program, so that in VS Code I can Ctrl+Click and view type definitions, get IntelliSense suggestions, etc. It's my understanding that this is what the haskell-language-server does, correct me if I'm wrong.

I am currently on week 4 of cohort #3. After messing around for a while and getting errors, I decided to recreate a clean environment. I created a fresh Ubuntu VM, setup nix, and did the following steps:

1. clone plutus-apps repo
2. clone plutus-pioneer-program repo
3. consult week4 cabal.project to obtain plutus-apps commit ea1bfc6a49ee731c67ada3bfb326ee798001701a, and then checkout said commit in the plutus-apps repo.
4. run `nix-shell` in plutus-apps repo, wait for it to finish
5. within the launched nix shell from step 4, cd over to week04 in the plutus-pioneer-program repo, run `haskell-language-server`
6. haskell-language-server command eventually fails due to needing cabal-update to be run (this was printed in the output)
7. run `cabal update`, wait for it to finish
8. re-run `haskell-language-server`, it eventually fails with the below error:

```
GHC runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   sqlite3_fts3_may_be_corrupt
whilst processing object file
   /nix/store/p2b0z9ajriig2krxkyn3n3wf1ph4bmzw-persistent-sqlite-lib-persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4-B4U7gZMAoFwD1W7QEEZsue/HSpersistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4-B4U7gZMAoFwD1W7QEEZsue.o
The symbol was previously defined in
   /nix/store/b18hn2jh564d3f4hg5mpk639dh4cr45f-direct-sqlite-lib-direct-sqlite-2.3.26/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/direct-sqlite-2.3.26-Gg0YVBPVrMk3LDxZxB2Bzf/HSdirect-sqlite-2.3.26-Gg0YVBPVrMk3LDxZxB2Bzf.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
2022-02-13 15:46:37.022720678 [ThreadId 481] INFO hls:  File:     /home/ben/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week04/src/Week04/Vesting.hs
Hidden:   no
Range:    1:1-2:1
Source:   compiler
Severity: DsError
Message: 
  loadObj
  "/nix/store/p2b0z9ajriig2krxkyn3n3wf1ph4bmzw-persistent-sqlite-lib-persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.20210212/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4-B4U7gZMAoFwD1W7QEEZsue/HSpersistent-sqlite-2.13.0.4-B4U7gZMAoFwD1W7QEEZsue.o":
  failed
2022-02-13 15:46:37.023051069 [ThreadId 445] INFO hls:  finish: User TypeCheck (took 5.05s)
2022-02-13 15:46:37.044108638 [ThreadId 883] INFO hls:  finish: GetHie (took 0.02s)
2022-02-13 15:46:37.044666524 [ThreadId 906] INFO hls:  finish: GenerateCore (took 0.00s)
Files that failed:
 * /home/ben/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week04/src/Week04/Trace.hs
 * /home/ben/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week04/src/Week04/Vesting.hs
```

From Googling around, it seems the issue has to do with the `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds        #-}` pragma in both those files, which is a core Haskell language extension. You can also see this from the error above, the `Range:` field talks about the first line of Vesting.hs, which is the DataKinds pragma. If this pragma is removed, the error goes away, however Vesting.hs and Trace.hs depend on it, and other errors are generated.

As best I can tell, there are somehow packages associated with this extension that either nix, cabal, or haskell-language-server have somehow duplicated. Or something. This is where my knowledge runs out.

Does anyone have any input here? How can this error be resolved?